# Copy Airflow project into Airflow DAGs directory

Tags: python, airflow

I have an Airflow project with the following structure

```
my_project
 |
dags-custom-|custom_operator1.py
 |          |custom_operator2.py
 |          |custom_hook1.py
 |
my_dag.py
```

Normally, if I have only my_dag.py I would do

`cp my_dag.py ~/airflow/dags/`

However, in this case I am not sure what should I do to load the project into Airflow DAGs list?

should I do `cp ~/my_project/ ~/airflow/dags/`?

Answer (score 1):

Airflow tries to parse every python file as a DAG and if it finds that a python file has the DAG context, then it is loaded. In your case, you are correct, just copy over the project to airflow DAGs.

Assuming that you are using the docker image to run airflow, it would be advisable to mount your project's root into the airflow DAG root like this:

`./my_project/:/opt/airflow/dags`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do it as you suggested but now I am getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom'" when trying to do 'from custom.custom_operator1 import MyClass'. Can you help me with this too?

Comment: yes. you need to set your python environment correctly. generally all folders within the DAG are part of the environment. Is `custom` a subdirectory of the DAG folder? If not can you qualify the name from the subdirectory? So do `from dags.custom.custom_operator1 import MyClass`

Comment: Custom is a subdirectory of the dags as in the schema in the question. I tried all `from dags.custom.custom_operator1 import MyClass`, `from my_project.dags.custom.custom_operator1 import MyClass`, `from custom.custom_operator1 import MyClass` nothing works. I get ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: hmm. this is a tough one. i would recommend opening ipython and getting a sense of what the environment is like.